# synchrozie get method from map?

Tags: java, collections, synchronization

in order to synchrozie my map get method I use

```
myObj = myMap.get("aaa"); 

if (myobj==null)
    synchronize (someObject){
        myObj = mymap.get("aaa");  
        if (myobj==null){
            myObj = createNew();
            myMap.put(myObj);

    }
 }
return myObj;
```

Is that the besdt way. asking the null condition twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

synchronizing the `get` only isn't very useful. `get` does not change the state of the map. You would also have to synchronize the `put` (with the same object monitor). And you can use `Collections.synchronizedMap(..)` or [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) for that

Update: for `get & then put` you can use `ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent(..)`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to write it . Just added the map put line . thanks a lot.